# Is there any news about Hunter x Hunter since March 2016?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I was searching on the internet and I found [this article on Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-03-14/hunter-x-hunter-manga-to-return-for-1st-time-since-august-2014/.99778),

> A page on the Shonen Jump+ website announced that Yoshihiro Togashi is resuming his *Hunter × Hunter* manga in the Ankoku Tairiku (Dark Continent) arc. This year's 16th issue of Shueisha's *Weekly Shonen Jump* magazine will reveal more details on Saturday.

Is there anyone who knows if this was real, and is there any other news about the return of *Hunter x Hunter*?

Comment: Unless you are an insider within the industry, there is no further information at this moment aside from the details provided in the article that you've linked. The source itself is legitimate because 1) it comes from a reputable site that reports anime and manga news, and 2) the news comes from the publisher directly. It's already all there. The only questions on the minds of fans is how long until the next hiatus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally we got one great news.

#### According to this [Link](http://www.hngn.com/articles/194561/20160402/hunter-x-debut-adult-swims-toonami-starting-april-16-tweet.htm) and [wiki](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/News):

> It's been a big past few weeks for "Hunter x Hunter" fans. After
> Shueisha's "Weekly Shonen Jump" announced mid-March that "Hunter x
> Hunter" would be making its return to the magazine (confirmed for
> April 18) after being on hiatus since 2014, fans in America now have
> even more to look forward to, as Adult Swim's Toonami revealed that an
> English dub for the series will be aired on the network starting April
> 16.
>
> The announcement was made Friday during a pre-show feature on the
> Adult Swim website Toonami: Pre-flight. The series will make its
> premiere on the network starting April 16 at 1 a.m.

[image]

Comment: @LightYagami this question will probably be duplicated alot in the coming months. Can you modify your answer to have the year like `April 18,2016` so that as this question is duplicated the reader will have a bit more clarity on the solution?