# Is there any news about Hunter x Hunter since June 2016?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I know that it's been put on hold for a bit, but does anyone have any recent information on updates or progress?

The last post I read was from Dec.21 '14 so it's been a bit.

Comment: For the close voters. As my answer below points out, it is not an unannounced event.

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30513/is-there-any-news-about-hunter-x-hunter/31420#31420

Answer (score 1):

If we are both talking about the manga, there indeed is some more information.

[Shonen Jump](http://www.shonenjump.com/p/sp/1603/hxh/) announced that Yoshihiro Togashi will be resuming HxH in the dark continent arc. More details were said to be released in this year's 16th issue of Shueisha's Weekly Shonen Jump, which they did.

HxH has been releasing chapters for the last 9 weeks, starting in week 18 of 2016.

You can also keep a check on [Hiatus x Hiatus](https://hiatus-hiatus.rhcloud.com/) which maintains a nice diagram of when chapters were (not) released.

As for the anime, currently, there is not enough source material to go build an anime upon and is therefore still on hiatus. For the continuation of the anime, no time indication has been given whatsoever

Comment: Just for some extra info, do you know what the last volume and chapter was that released? I've barely started that manga and I'd like to know how deep the rabbit hole goes.

Comment: @Hikari 359 Chapters. Of which, at the point of writing, 9 have not yet been released in a volume format. [hxh chapters wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_chapters)